# Where to find C standard function prototypes easily

Tags: c, linux

When coding C# in IDEs like Visual Studio, it is quite handy to "jump to definition or declarations". So that we know the prototypes/interfaces of functions/APIs easily.

**Question:** 
Is there an easy way to look up standard C functions prototypes? like a database or index of function declarations, or a website gives searching by function names, or a *NIX command?

Solutions that work/integrate within VIM are great.

If you are recommending download source code and then `grep`, could you give a grep command that returns more accurate results. Since the `grep` may return all lines that has the name of that function.

Comment: `man standardfunction` works pretty well most of the time...

Comment: One alternative that might work with Vim is the use of `ctags`. You could build a database of system functions by proces /usr/include (would take a while to generate). But it would provide ll the prototypes. TO get an idea of ctags see: http://andrew.stwrt.ca/posts/vim-ctags

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *NIX command?

Yes, the command is [`man`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/man), for example `man fopen`. Type `man man` on the command line to read its manual page. If the same keyword has multiple meanings (and therefore multiple [man pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page)), you may need to specify the right [section number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections), i.e. `man 3 time`.

> Solutions that work/integrate within VIM are great.

In `vim`, to view the man page for the word under cursor, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: man returns info about the linux command, not the C functions. For example. ``man time`` returns use of linux command ``time``, not the interface of ``time()`` function in ``<time.h>``.

Comment: @PengZhang: `man 3 time` to see the man page for the C function.

Comment: @PengZhang the manpages are organized in sections, see [here how they are organized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections), if a keyword exists in more than one section you can add the section number.

Comment: How can I tell ``shift + K`` the section number of man I want? Is ``shift+K`` defined as a ``nmap``?

Answer (score 3):

I would say that one place to find out prototypes is C standard itself. You can download latest draft for C99 and C11 from [here](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/standards). Beside that I agree with `man 3 func` approach.